# Want image in my android app to pause for 5 seconds and then slide off screen to the left

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

when the app opens I want the image to appear immediately and remain still for 5 seconds and then after those 5 seconds have the image slide off screen to the left, instead my image appears like I want it but as soon as it appears it immediately begins to slides off screen, I would like to achieve this animation in code and not in xml. appreciate any advice, thank you.

```
package your.package2.test3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.AnimationSet;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Test3Activity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);

    AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);

    TranslateAnimation Anim1 = new TranslateAnimation(0,0,0,0);
    Anim1.setDuration(5000);
    TranslateAnimation Anim2 = new TranslateAnimation(0,-300,0,0);
    Anim2.setDuration(2000);
    animSet.addAnimation(Anim1);
    animSet.addAnimation(Anim2);
    img.startAnimation(animSet);
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any situations where creating a thread just to sleep a duration is a good idea. Instead, try [`postDelayed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29):

```
img.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0,-300,0,0);
        anim.setDuration(2000);
        img.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Thread for displaying the image and the Thread.sleep(5000) method. I think this is actually the best practice in doing this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Thread timer = new Thread() {
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("your.package2.test3.A New Class");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
```